# Locking in QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

A simple exercise in threading here. Say I have a static lock, a web request, and a thread queue thread. Will the following cause a problem (ignoring the quality of the code itself):

```
static object locker = new object();
static MyObject obj = new MyObject();

public static void Update(){
   lock(locker){
      obj.Foo = "biz";
      DoStuff();
   }
}

public static void DoStuff(){
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(args => {
      lock(locker){
         obj.Foo = "bar";
      }
   });
}
```

The example is contrived, but the concept holds :).

Comment: If your question about deadlock you haven't it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not cause a problem.  If this is called a single time, `DoStuff()` will not be able to acquire the lock until `Update()`'s code has exited the lock.  However, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is an asynchronous call, so the lock will be able to be released, which in turn will allow `DoStuff()` to process.

Comment: OK, I was pretty convinced of the same thing, but needed to get my head out of it for a minute - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't.  The only gotcha specific to thread pool threads is that the thread pool grows relatively slowly, so if you blocked a lot waiting for locks you can cause performance issues.